# How can I change the checkbox styles and icons when hover on it in Material-UI React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui in my project, and I have a Checkbox with a red color.

I would like to show checked Icon when someone would hover on Checkbox only.

It would be hidden when not hovered.  I don't seem to find the proper selector for that. I would love any suggestions about what can I do about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Some notice points:

- Use Material-UI [nesting selector](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors) to catch the SVG element since the `<Checkbox />` is a lib element which has a static dom structure.
- Use `&:hover` to catch `onMouseOver` event.
- Use `d: path(value)` to pass props `d`'s value to SVG's child element `<path />`

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AcUnit from "@material-ui/icons/AcUnit";
// import Accessibility from "@material-ui/icons/Accessibility";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    background: "#f1f1f1",
    "&:hover": {
      "& span": {
        "& svg": {
          "& path": {
            d:
              "path('M12 2c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2s-.9 2-2 2-2-.9-2-2 .9-2 2-2zm9 7h-6v13h-2v-6h-2v6H9V9H3V7h18v2z')"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Checkbox className={classes.root} icon={<AcUnit />} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Try it online:

[image: Edit amazing-golick-rjmcs]

---

Refer: the `<Checkbox />` structure which can be seen in browser

```html
<span
  class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root PrivateSwitchBase-root-8 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary makeStyles-root-85 MuiIconButton-colorSecondary"
  aria-disabled="false"
>
  <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
    <input
      class="PrivateSwitchBase-input-11"
      type="checkbox"
      data-indeterminate="false"
      value=""
    /><svg
      class="MuiSvgIcon-root"
      focusable="false"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      aria-hidden="true"
      role="presentation"
    >
      <path
        d="M22 11h-4.17l3.24-3.24-1.41-1.42L15 11h-2V9l4.66-4.66-1.42-1.41L13 6.17V2h-2v4.17L7.76 2.93 6.34 4.34 11 9v2H9L4.34 6.34 2.93 7.76 6.17 11H2v2h4.17l-3.24 3.24 1.41 1.42L9 13h2v2l-4.66 4.66 1.42 1.41L11 17.83V22h2v-4.17l3.24 3.24 1.42-1.41L13 15v-2h2l4.66 4.66 1.41-1.42L17.83 13H22z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I was wondering about changing the path of svg but didn't know how to do it. Your solution taught me a lot. Thank you again

Comment: Refer to the docs to see also how to set up the "checked" icon: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-checkbox/#icon